# Подсчет уникальных одинаковых из таблицы

Tags: php, sql, redbeanphp

В таблице есть поля id, status ...

Каким образом можно получить кол-во одинаковых значений, при этом получить такой вариант `[id] => val`

Данное решение подсчитывает не совсем так как нужно:

```
\R::getCol('SELECT COUNT(status) FROM ideas GROUP BY status');
```

Результат сейчас такой:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
)
```

А нужно, что бы в ключах был id, иначе не понятно в каком id какое кол-во одинаковых значений.

P.S.: использую RedBeans.

Comment: Не совсем понятна схема таблицы. Если ID не является primary key и может повторятся то возможно вам поможет что-то типа: SELECT id, status, COUNT(*) FROM ideas GROUP BY id, status;

Comment: ID у меня primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\R::getAssoc('SELECT status, COUNT(*) FROM ideas GROUP BY status');
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает четко!